# Test if user has access to write on a page in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

In my DisplayViewWebPart I have a part of my code that need to be protected in the way that the user will only see it on the page if the user is allowed to write/create content on a specific page.

This code runs on my front page:

```
protected override DataResultSet Result
{
    get
    {
        DataResultSet result = new DataResultSet();
        if (logic to check if user is allowed to write)
        {

        }
        result.Add(new DataResultRow());
        return result;
    }
}
```

the page the user must have access to is. "http://sites/domain/nyheder/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

Can someone help me since I'm really stuck at the moment.
thanks

**Edit**

I tried this and it seems to work but I dont know for sure.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp16/sites/domain/nyheder/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
        {
            SPBasePermissions permissionToCheck = SPBasePermissions.ManageLists;

            SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;

            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(user.LoginName, permissionToCheck))
            {
                result.Add(new DataResultRow());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the method, SPListItem.DoesUserHavePermissions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472022.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Do you need to check user permission on the web or ListItem?